# Split a tensor in torch

Tags: torch

Given an input tensor of size `n x 2A x B x C`, how to split it into two tensors, each of size `n x A x B x C`? Essentially, `n` is the batch size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `torch.split`:

```
torch.split(input_tensor, split_size_or_sections=A, dim=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like:

```
tensor_a = torch.Tensor(n, 2A, B,C)
-- Initialize tensor_a with the data

tensor_b = torch.Tensor(n, A, B, C)
tensor_b = tensor_a[{{},1,{},{}}]
tensor_c = torch.Tensor(n, A, B, C)
tensor_c = tensor_a[{{},2,{},{}}]
```